# How to add css styles in app.css for ember js addon

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, ember-addon, ember-cli-addons

I am creating ember addons and there are few css styles which this addon requires to work properly!

How do i add them so that when a consuming application uses this addon the particular css styles are directly added to the app.css file of the consuming application?

Eg:
addon: dropdown-addon requires a style

```
.active-menu {
    background-color: #4183C4;
}
```

consuming application: online-form

when online-form is using dropdown-addon i want .active-menu to be added to app.css automatically!

Comment: Inside the addon directory, create a styles folder. Inside that, create a css file with your addon's styles. They should be included automatically with the consuming app's css. Thats how I did it for my addon. https://github.com/blessenm/ember-cli-bm-select/blob/master/addon/styles/bm-select.css

Comment: are you sure? i already tried it but it didn work!
Also i tried it with the dummy testing application! Is it meant to work only with consuming application and not the test dummy application?

Comment: Well I tried installing my addon on a new app and the addon css was getting appended to the vendor.css file. Im not sure about the dummy app. I need to do a complete check with the latest version of ember and cli.

Comment: right let me check it too and get back!

Answer (score 5):

- Create the file `vendor/style.css` with your custom css
- In `index.js` add:

```js
module.exports = {

  //...
  //...

  included: function(app) {
    app.import('vendor/style.css');
  }

  //...
  //...

}
```

Note: The css code will be added to dist/assets/vendor.css

Comment: hmmm so the key here is "included" hook right! i was looking for this hook. let me confirm and then get back.

Comment: This definitely works.  You can also import css from your app/styles directory if you're wanting to match the Ember app's code structure.  Either way it will be included in your Ember app's `vendor.css` file.